# Graphviz, order of nodes in left-to-right digraph (Markov chain)

Tags: graph, graphviz, markov-chains

I'd like to use graphviz to make a graph of a simple Markov chain. Below is the the code I used and the graph I got.

How can I make all nodes sit on the a horizontal axis in the same order as they're in the `.dot` file? Apparently the order of nodes in the source file doesn't solve the problem.

(*Nice to have*) How can I make the edges between 2 and 3, 3 and 4 and 4 and 5 symetric about the horizontal axis on which the nodes sit? You can see that *p* edges are straight but *q* are curved. I'd like both of them curved.

[image]

```
digraph {
    rankdir=LR;
    node [shape = circle];

    1
    2
    3
    4
    5
    6

    1 -> 1[label="1"];

    2 -> 1[label="q"];
    2 -> 3[label="p"];

    3 -> 2[label="q"];
    3 -> 4[label="p"];

    4 -> 3[label="q"];
    4 -> 5[label="p"];

    5 -> 4[label="q"];
    5 -> 6[label="p"];

    6 -> 6[label="1"];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most important step is to make sure all nodes are in the same rank:

```
digraph 
{
    rankdir=TB;
    node [ shape = circle ];
    { rank = same; 1 2 3 4 5 6 }

    2 -> 3[label="p"];
    3 -> 4[label="p"];
    4 -> 5[label="p"];
    5 -> 6[label="p"];
    6:ne -> 6:nw[label="1"];

    edge[ dir = back ];
    1:ne -> 1:nw[label="1"];
    1 -> 2[ label="q"];
    2 -> 3[label="q"];
    3 -> 4[label="q"];
    4 -> 5[label="q"];
}
```

yields

[image]